# Move Google Apps primary domain to another account, forced email downtime?

Tags: google-workspace, migration

I'm trying to close Google Apps for companyA.com and merge it into a different Google Apps account. It will live on as "another domain" (not an alias) under the companyB.com Google Apps account.

Migrating email, docs, calendars, sites etc is easy enough, no problems with that.

The issue is I don't believe I can add companyA.com as a New Domain of companyB.com until I delete Company A's Google Apps account and wait 24hrs? Won't email be completely down for companyA.com employees during that time?

Am I missing something or does moving from one Google Apps account to another effectively force a 24hr email shutdown? Just seems strange because moving from say, GoDaddy to Google Apps wouldn't cause any email downtime.